# Laravel 5.2 connect to MS SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2. Out-Of-The-Box it does not have a MS SQL connection in the

`config\database.php`

so I made the following changes

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => '10.0.0.1', // Provide IP address here
        'database' => 'TheDatabase',
        'username' => 'Fred',
        'password' => 'Flintstone',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

**I am getting the following error**

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55: could not find driver
```

I have the latest SQL Drivers. I have checked the php.ini but I don't know what I am looking at in this file.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, try try again.;-)

Firstly, you need to download:

**Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=20098

**Then you need to download the PHP SQL Drivers from**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx

copy the above files eg

```
php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll                   <--- See the 56. that is PHP ver 5.6
php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

to you php\ext director

Once the above is installed, go and edit you ***php.ini*** file (found in your php directory)

Look for: Windows Extensions
And below the first extention add the following (I was using PHP 5.6):

```
extension php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll                   
extension php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Ensure that there are **NO** semicolons in front of the above inserts
Ensure that there **ARE** semicolons in front of any other extensions relating to sqlsrv.

That is it.